# Extracting tables using pandas read_html function?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

This is an unusual problem. I am trying to extract a table from certain website(link cant be given because of security). The problem is that the site will load the table when accessed through website but when we use `inspect element` on any values/tables on that table it is not visible. It just show `<html>_</html>` with some scripts and links inside. Initially I tried to extract table using `beautifulsoup` but it was unsuccessful. Then I used pandas
`pandas.read_html(html)` but the site contains more than one table and its output is something like this

```
[     Code                   Name  
 0    A                      John   
 1    B                      Terry
 2    C                      Kitty 


    Column 1 Column 2    Column 3
0       1   0.6173661242    8
1       2   0.7232098163    20
2       3   0.9954581943    39
3       4   0.5595425507    18
4       5   0.9644025159    20
5       6   0.3914102544    29
6       7   0.0154642132    49

....

[873 rows x 3 columns],

0\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  
 0                                                  0    ]
```

Then I tried something like this `pandas.read_html(html, match="Column 1")` it returns this error

> ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Column 1'

any idea how we can use read_html to extract tables?

Comment: You can probably index into the specific table you want. It looks like you want the second table (?) So you could probably do `df = pd.read_table(url)[1]`

Comment: It just output whole website. I think the site(for security) uses some other way to output table and not using normal table html tag.

Comment: when you did `pd.read_table(html)` what was the length of the list you got back?

Comment: It doesn't show any length it output the whole website

Comment: you said it output something like that (in your post), which clearly looks like a list to me. store the result to a variable and print it's length

Comment: I believe you meant this `len(pd.read_table(url)[1])` but its outputting the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122215/discussion-between-m-klugerford-and-eka).

Answer (score 0):

When data scraping off a secure website, the website can be using Java to load the tables so you never see the HTML-styled code. This could be why BeautifulSoup is not returning anything.

Does the "scripts and links inside" look like Java?

Maybe have a look at [Selenium?](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)